# Adding global variable on flycheck

Tags: spacemacs, flycheck, javascript, js2-mode

I tried to add this to my eslint global variable

```
"globals": {
    "document": false,
    "navigator": false,
    "window": false,
    "rndr": false,
    "shrd": false,
    "path": true,
    "$": false // <--- I also added this
}
```

but still I am getting `undeclared variable or function`.

Here is the flycheck verification.
[image]

But the error is still there.

[image]

Please, I need some guidance how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: You can use comments to declare variables as global. Both `eslint` and `js2-mode` should understand them. https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 yes it is, but you will write it on every file that use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `flycheck` and `js2-mode`, the error is shown by `js2-mode` not by `flycheck`.

You can disable `js2-mode` errors by setting

```
  (setq js2-mode-show-parse-errors nil)
  (setq js2-mode-show-strict-warnings nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `js2-global-externs` to your liking. It applies to every `js2-mode` buffer, so you won't need to duplicate your customization.

> A list of any extern names you’d like to consider always declared.
>   This list is global and is used by all ‘js2-mode’ files.
>   You can create buffer-local externs list using ‘js2-additional-externs’.